# Generate product description from 2 different storeviews

Tags: magento-1.8, product, sql, store-view

We use magento 1.8.1

I already have 3 different storeviews in 3 different languages.

Now I would like to have a 4th storeview, but with the product description of storeview 1 and 2 combined together.

This new storeview is going to be used for displaying items in a app.
And I can't change the code of that.

We have over 13000 sku in our store, so manually doing this isn't an option.

Is there a way to automatically do this? This could also be done on the items which are visible and Searchable. (Around 2000sku)

Resumé
What i would like to have, in magento backend (not front end)

Description storeview 1 (Code: nl) (also standard scope) 
and 
description storeview 2 (Code: en) 
copied and merged to the new storeview 4 (dutch + english combined, Code: mobile)

Does anyone have a solution for this? Can i do this in sql? Or has anyone an other solution?

EDIT 28-05-2016:
The script blow works great, but now i want to only do this with products with an product id of 25000 and newer.
How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot using the standard product's model approach because the store view is bonded to the product itself during the load.

But you may try a "lower level" approach by accessing the resource model:

```
Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')
  ->getAttributeRawValue($productId, 'my_attribute_name', $storeId);
```

Just pass the `$storeId` to get the value you need from the store view you need.

So you can use this script I made for you:

```
<?php
require_once 'abstract.php';

class Mage_Shell_DescMerge extends Mage_Shell_Abstract
{
    const STORE_ID_1 = 1; // Replace this with correct value
    const STORE_ID_2 = 2; // Replace this with correct value
    const STORE_DESTINATION = 3; // Replace this with correct value

    public function run()
    {
        $catalogResourceModel = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product');
        $catalogAction = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action');


        $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
        foreach ($collection as $product) {
            $productId = $product->getId();

            echo "Updating product $productId\n";

            $descrStore1 = $catalogResourceModel
                ->getAttributeRawValue($productId, 'description', static::STORE_ID_1);

            $descrStore2 = $catalogResourceModel
                ->getAttributeRawValue($productId, 'description', static::STORE_ID_2);


            $attrs = array(
                'description' => $descrStore1.'<br />'.$descrStore2,
            );

            $catalogAction
                ->updateAttributes(array($productId), $attrs, static::STORE_DESTINATION);
        }
    }
}

$shell = new Mage_Shell_DescMerge();
$shell->run();
```

**NOTE:**

This script must be placed in a PHP file inside `shell` path of your magento

You can run it from shell using the following command:

```
cd /yourmagentopath/shell
php -q scriptname.php
```

I created a shell script because this operation may take a long time, so you'dd beter to run via shell to avoid web timeouts.

**WARNING:**

Make a full database backup before running this script to make sure it is working in the way you expect.

Comment: I don't want to display it in a normal store. I would like to have the product description te be copied from 2 storeviews to a new storeview.

Comment: You can do it, I added an implementation example to my answer. See if it fits your needings.

Comment: Will this generate THE description in THE backend? (I updated my question too)

Comment: My script can merge the description from store1 and store2 and merge them in store3 (or 4 if you like). Is is not intended to run in frontend, it is an update script you can run from shell if you like. Descriptions on store3 will be merged both for frontend and backend. Is this what you need?

Comment: That sounds like what i need. How do i run this? Just past it into a php file?

Comment: I suggest to run it as PHP shell script. It may take time to run and you may have a timeout if calling from web. Now I'm out of my office. Later I'll paste you a full php shell script or you may have a look in Magento shell folder to see how to include it.

Comment: If you could past a full script that would be great !!!

Comment: I updated my answer with a full PHP shell script. Please make a DB backup before running it. Just make sure it is working as expected.

Comment: Hi Riccardo. This works great. But now i want it only to be applied from product id 25000 and higher .... how can i do that?

Comment: Just make a check on $productId.

Comment: could you add that for me in the code above?